# htaccess wildcard redirect to parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

a simple request I'm sure but can't for the life of me find an answer.

I would like the following...

`http://example.co.uk/menu/item1`, `http://example.co.uk/menu/item2`, `http://example.co.uk/menu/item3` etc.

To redirect to `http://example.co.uk/menu/`.

Currently I am using the rule below but am getting a redirect loop on `/menu/`.

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/menu/.*$ http://example.co.uk/menu/
```

How do I create a rule that redirects only what I require and leaves `/menu/` accessible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak your regex a little by matching 1 or more characters after `/menu/`:

```
RewriteRule ^menu/(.+)$ /menu/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, I worked it out in the end. Finally. The below is what I needed. Thanks for your help though.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/menu/$
RewriteRule ^menu/(.*) http://example.co.uk/menu/ [L,R=301]`