# .htaccess rule for redirecting to parent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect one of my urls to the parent folder using `.htaccess` file. I have tried the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /test/ [L,R=301]
```

found from [htaccess wildcard redirect to parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994529/htaccess-wildcard-redirect-to-parent-folder/21995256#21995256) but it is not working (logs show too many redirects).

I also tried the other rules below but none of them worked

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/test/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /test/ [END,NC]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /test/ [L,R=301]
```

The OS is ubuntu server. Any help or pointers is appreciated. Please let me know if I can furnish any other details to debug. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to **redirect** anything inside `test` folder (`/test/XXX`) to `/test/` ?

Comment: @JustinIurman - Yes

Comment: Well, your first rule should work. I suggest you to use the network tool from chrome (for instance, or equivalent) to see what's going wrong. This debug will help

Comment: Do you use `test.php` or `test.html` ?

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: @Croises - test.php

Comment: @starkeen - no other rules

Comment: @JustinIurman - can you please elaborate on this? i checked the apache logs but it has the message too many redirects nothing else

Comment: If this is all you have in htaccess then your last two rules should work fine  because you are using the `END` and `℅{ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS}`  both works as anti loop protection on internal redirects. If this is 301 redirect then you will need to use `RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/test [NC]`

Comment: This should work for you . Make sure to test this in a new browser or clear your browser cache : `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /test/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: @starkeen - still no luck :(. this is frustrating. appreciate all the help..

Answer (score 1):

Following should work considering the parent directory is `test`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(test/).* /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. tried this now, but didnt work. the other urls still throw 404 error

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: there was a typo in answer, missed adding * , see the updated answer.

Comment: Not Found
The requested URL /test/cc was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80

Comment: still getting the same thing. if you see the question, this was my first try actually.. i am guessing the rule is fine, but something else is failing, but couldnt figure what.. any pointers are appreciated

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=58d6d64b-b7ad-5151-b8d7-76ce601405a4 check here, its passing the rule. Do you have any more rules in your htaccess ?

Comment: nope, no other rules in the htaccess. Considering that the rule is correct, is there some other possible reason for this not to work?

Comment: do you have /test or /test/ giving valid response from the web server?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ /test/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache or try with other browser ?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^rootFName(.*) /rFile.php  [QSA,R=301,L]
```